# hypertarget works for files but not URLs

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls

I want to link directly to a `\hypertarget` inside a document.  If works file to file, but not to URL.
The linking MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview={FitH top},colorlinks=true,extension=pdf}

\hyperbaseurl{http://www.elfsoft2000.com/temp/}

\begin{document}
\href{hypertarget.pdf#target}{click here}
\end{document}
```

The target MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,
    colorlinks=true,extension=}

\begin{document}
Nope, not right
\newpage
\hypertarget{target}{This is the target.}
\end{document}
```

I preloaded a copy onto my web site.  You can switch from file-to-file to URL mode using the extension=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959347.

I switched my default viewer to IE and it works as is.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax depends on the PDF program/plugin that you are using. For Adobe Reader, the syntax for the URL are specified in [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf).

The name for the destination is given with key `nameddest` in the URL:

```
\href{hypertarget.pdf\#nameddest=target}{click here}
```

Comment: I can't get nameddest to work even in file mode.  I did discover that the pdfstartview was interfering.  Maybe I need a newer version of acrobat.

Comment: I decided to switch from using \hypertarget to using \hyperdef, which I originally avoided since I had no idea what to use for "category".  P.S Ignore what I said about pdfstartview.

Comment: In URL mode, it you put the cursor over the anchor it will give you the URL (but not in file mode).  It puts a # before the category, but only a dot between the category and the label.