# reference to local html-file with anchor (hashmark #) via \href

Tags: hyperref

I try to link to my local html-files with `\href` from `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:relative_path/filename.html#anchor}{test}
\end{document}
```

It also works quite well only for the file itself. The *anchor* is cut off from the link in several pdf viewers such as Evince and Okular.

Interestingly, substituting `run:` by `http://`

```
\href{http://relative_path/filename.html#anchor}{hhh}
```

offers the anchor in Evince's and Okular's views.

Is there any way to get the `run:` to also provide the anchor?

Comment: \# works for me, but you might try spelling ancor or anchor consistently.

Comment: @John Yeah Typos, you'r right. For me it doesn't work \#. don't know why.

Comment: One of the references I want to use:  \href{run:html/classtest_framework_1_1firmwareupdate_1_1_firmwareupdate_factory_1_1_firmwareupdate_factory.html#a31e1daca3d8db1b65844b8cce35daaf4}{FirmwareupdateFactory}

Comment: Oh, for web access I set \hyperbaseurl to the local folder.  I don't know any way to do local files AND html at the same time.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128087/hypertarget-works-for-files-but-not-urls

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. Does it help? If not, please comment.

Comment: I'm not sure about run: but certainly the related file: protocol doesn't officially support `#` and hyperref removes it, with run the pdfviewer has to pass a local filename to the application, and `#` isn't [art of a filename, so I suspect this is by design

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the test to

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:relative_path/filename.html#anchor}{test}


\href{http:relative_path2/filename.html#anchor2}{test}
\end{document}
```

Then you can look at the links hyperref is adding, which are:

```
/Subtype/Link/A<</F(relative_path/filename.html)/S/Launch/Win<</P(anchor)/F(relative_path/filename.html)
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http:relative_path2/filename.html#anchor2)
```

Note that the `#` fragid syntax is really part of the `http:` URI scheme. The `file:` and PDF-specific `run:` schemes really expect a *filename* to pass to the local application to open a file on the local system and `#` is not part of the filename and so `hyperref` removes it.