# Possibility of Moving Hyperlinked Files Without Breaking the Link

Tags: xetex, hyperref, kile

I have created a tex file using Kile and have used xelatex package to convert that file to pdf. Now there are nearly 50 audio files (in mp3 and wav format) hyperlinked with the document in several place. It works fine for me in my system. To hyperlink the mp3 files I have used hyperref package and used the command \href{run:/path/to/my/file.ext}{text displayed}. But, now I want to move the pdf file and the audio files to another directory (and another computer) without breaking the hyperlink. Is it possible? If not, then please give me any alternative way out.

Comment: You can try and embed the files as attachments to the PDF (see [`embedfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) for example). It'll make the PDF more... well, portable. Yes, a more portable Portable Document Format.

Comment: For a similar situation I had to reset \hyperbaseurl when I moved it.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128087/hypertarget-works-for-files-but-not-urls